# For loop is being escaped due to use of .parentNode

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I delete `parentNode` from the code below, the forloop is *not* escaped. Any thoughts as to why **parentNode** is doing this?

**Edit:** I've corrected the syntax noted in the comments.

```
        for (var i=0; i < itemlist.length; i++) {

            var newprice = basepricearray[i]*multiplier;
            var newprice2 = Number(newprice).toFixed(2);                
            var wrapper = itemlist[i].parentElement;           

            if (basepricearray[i] == "0.00") {

                wrapper.classList.remove("hidepricing100");
                var costbox = itemlist[i].parentNode;
                costbox.innerText = "Free";

            } 
        }
```

Thank you!

Comment: Single equals sets a value, Double Equals checks the value. Since you are setting a value and not checking, it will validate as being true.

Comment: Even after making this change, I still am seeing the for loop being escaped :(

Comment: does the node have innerText? Is there an error in the console?

Comment: There is no error in the console. I just tried removing 'parentNode' from the code and the for loop does not get escaped. parentNode is absolutely the culprit. I'm just not sure how else to get the parent of an index of get ElementsByClassName.

Comment: `try { console.log(itemlist[i].parentNode) } catch ( e ) { console.log(e); }` Put this above where you are trying to access it currently.  See what gets logged.

Comment: Put it where you commented out parentNode, that snippet is just a debug to see what's going on, or you can use inspector and step thru the js and see what went wrong. I would recommend using the inspector and stepping thru the js because it is a very important and powerful, it will help you so much more if you can figure out how to use it

Comment: It returns one div within the console. This for loop is only executing 1 out of 2 times.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I've removed code that is working.

Comment: Likely due to variable hoisting. Try change `var` to `let` and see if it works.

Comment: " Cannot set property 'innerText' of undefined" as a result of using let.